# Angular - Testing component - Error when returning Promise.reject from mock

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, promise, angular-components

**I have a component unit test which isn't handling a promise rejection from a mock in the way I expected it to.**

I have this function on a component which sends some data to `addUserToOrganisation` and handles the Promise that it returns:

```
 public onSubmit() {
    this.saveStatus = 'Saving';
    this.user = this.prepareSaveUser();
    this._userService.addUserToOrganisation(this.user)
    .then(() => this._router.navigate(['/profile']))
    .catch(error => this.reportError(error));
  }
```

When testing this component, I have provided a mock for `UserService` which spies on the `addUserToOrganisation` endpoint and returns a Promise of some kind:

```
 mockUserService = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockUserService', ['getOrgId', 'addUserToOrganisation']);
 mockUserService.getOrgId.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('an id'));
 mockUserService.addUserToOrganisation.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
```

This works fine for happy paths (resolve) - I can test that `this._router.navigate()` is called and so on. Here is the passing test for this happy path:

```
it('should navigate to /profile if save is successful', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.userForm.controls['firstName'].setValue('John');
    component.userForm.controls['lastName'].setValue('Doe');
    component.userForm.controls['email'].setValue('j.d@gmail.com');
    component.onSubmit();

    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/profile']);
  }));
```

However, I am having trouble testing the 'sad' path. I alter my mock to return a `Promise.reject` and, although I have a `.catch` in `onSubmit`,  I am getting this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): no
```

So that's confusing. Here is my test for this sad path. Note that I change the response of the mock call.

```
it('should show Failed save status if the save function fails', fakeAsync(() => {
    mockUserService.addUserToOrganisation.and.returnValue(Promise.reject('no'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.userForm.controls['firstName'].setValue('John');
    component.userForm.controls['lastName'].setValue('Doe');
    component.userForm.controls['email'].setValue('j.d@gmail.com');
    component.onSubmit();

    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.saveStatus).toEqual('Failed! no');
  }));
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Promise rejections are supposed to be caught, having them unhandled will result in error in Zone.js promise implementation (which is used in Angular applications) and some others (Chrome, core-js promise polyfill, etc).

A rejection should be caught synchronously in order to be considered handled. It is guaranteed this way that an error will always be handled.

This is handled promise:

```
const p = Promise.reject();
p.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

This is unhandled promise:

```
const p = Promise.reject();
setTimeout(() => {
  p.catch(err => console.error(err));
}, 1000);
```

Even though a rejection will possibly be handled in future, there's no way how implementation can 'know' about that, so a promise is considered unhandled and `unhandledrejection` event is triggered.

The thing that creates the problem is

```
tick();
fixture.detectChanges();
```

If `tick()` is there 'just in case' and there's no real use of it, it shouldn't be there in the first place. If it should then code needs to be changed to not create unhandled promises:

```
mockUserService.addUserToOrganisation.and.callFake(() => Promise.reject('no'));
```

Comment: I tried removing the `tick()` and I still got an error. I don't quite understand how it would be unnecessary? However, changing my mock response from `returnValue...` to `callFake...` has done the trick. I don't think I 100% understand the nuance here though.

Comment: `callFake` creates a rejected promise at the moment when it's called, so it is chained with `.catch` during `component.onSubmit()` call and results in handled promise. `returnValue` accepts existing rejected promise which should be chained with `.catch` immediately but it isn't - because timer is moved to next tick with `tick()` before a rejection was caught in `component.onSubmit()`. The example with `setTimeout` shows exactly what's going on there. It should work without `tick()`. I can't say why you still get this error without it.

Comment: @EstusFlask it worked fine for me but it didn't cover the catch block in my code. I also wanted 100% code coverage for the method by covering Promise.resolve and Promise.reject

Comment: @PritamBohra Your code may differ from what was posted. I'd expect `.and.callFake(() => Promise.reject('no'))` to provide the coverage for `catch`.