# Unhandled promise rejection: Timeout thrown

Tags: angular, jasmine, testcase

I am working on unit test case in angular 12 and i discover this random behaviour of test case where i found that some times my test cases are working normally and some times it throwing this error "Unhandled promise rejection: Timeout thrown"

[Here is image of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0mpr.png)

Comment: When I would get an error like so, I have found this answer to help me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44455159/7365461.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.